# What does date.getDayAsString() refers?

Tags: jquery

In one of the source code I have seen date.getDayAsString(). What does that mean?

The code is:

```
var dateString3 = date.getDayAsString()+" "+date.getDate()+"/"+   (date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: i guess its a custom function to get day as string, like 0 as Sunday..!

Comment: But I didn't see this function in Date object methods and properties..

Comment: its might have been added like Date.prototype.getDayAsString = function() { .. };

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a query about a custom method which is not defined in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) does not have such function defined by default, that method might have been added to [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, like

```
if( !Date.prototype.getDayAsString )
    Date.prototype.getDayAsString = function() {
        var daysArray = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
        var dayNum = this.getDay();
        return daysArray[dayNum];
    };
}
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.getDayAsString());
```